# how to Iterate over a 4-dimensional tensor and pass 3-dimensional tensors to lstm layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

currenty I'm working on a seq2sql project and I'm stuck in this step.bellow is my code.

```python
inputs2=Input(shape=(C,3,100),name='col_tok')
col_lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(40,return_sequences=False),name='ColENC')
Col_last_hidden=tf.map_fn(lambda x:col_lstm_layer(x),
    inputs2)
```

inputs2 is a 4-dimensional tensor and I want to call col_lstm_layer for each element in the inputs2.so my solution is this but it gives the following error.

```
Initializer for variable map_7/while/ColENC/forward_lstm_17/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

and I know as the error says the solution is to add a lambda function but how to do it correctly.I changed my code with a lambda function as follows

```
Col_last_hidden=tf.map_fn(lambda x:col_lstm_layer(lambda:x),
    inputs2)
```

but it gives the flowing error.

```
Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'function'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

so how to Iterate over a 4-dimensional tensor and pass 3-dimensional tensors to lstm layer? Please help me.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515034/keras-tensorflow-initializer-for-variable-is-from-inside-a-control-flow-con

Comment: And a remark: `tf.map_fn(lambda x:col_lstm_layer(x), inputs2)` seems a bit overcomplicating it, why not just `tf.map_fn(col_lstm_layer,inputs2)`?

Comment: No Emil, I have already referred to that one. from that, I fixed the first error but I'm facing the second error now. i want to fix that error or have a separate solution to Iterate over a 4-dimensional tensor and pass 3-dimensional tensors to lstm layer.

Comment: I see. Just in case, did you read this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789822/tensorflow-creating-variables-in-fn-of-tf-map-fn-returns-value-error

Comment: i also tried `tf.map_fn(col_lstm_layer,inputs2)` Emil but it gives the same error

Comment: Dulmina, are you sure you are applying the lambda correctly? the `<class 'function'>` error seems to be caused by the wrong application of the lambda.

Comment: lambda application is wrong here if we want to get the output from the lambda function we should use equal operator like this `z=lambda:x` but at this stage, we cannot do that because we need to pass an input to the lstm layer.so yes,im looking for a correct way to apply lambda or any other way to achieve my requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186153/discussion-between-emil-vatai-and-dulmina).